# Pale Moon addon sdk exception

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to install my addon in Pale Moon but get this exception:

```
An exception occurred.
Error: Module `sdk/io/fs` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/io/fs.js
resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js 133
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm", line 137, in 
    aCallback(pipe.inputStream, aStatusCode, aRequest);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/net/url.js", line 49, in readAsync/<
    resolve(data);
...(long trace)
```

So what sdk i must use on pale moon to work with file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Firefox is Palemoon based on? If it's very old you shuld try SDK 1.14:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/jetpack/addon-sdk-1.14.zip

You should also look at the documentation for this version of the SDK ( run `cfx docs` ) as the current docs on will include modules that have been introduced more recently. sdk/io/fs, for example was only introduced last summer and shipped last fall.

Comment: With every Firefox release, a new versions of the SDK modules are shipped. We only ship the tools package ( that I linked to above ) when we introduce compatibility issues. We also assume that Firefox users are using the latest version ( because most Firefox users use the most recent version ). If you're using a forked version ( Pale Moon, IceWeasel, etc ) you may run into unexpected problems because we do not test with these versions.